# While trying to retrieve the AccesToken using HttpClient I am getting an error

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

While trying to retrieve the Acces Token from a windows server using HttpClient I am getting an error:

> "GSSAPI operation failed with error - An invalid status code was supplied (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)."

```
private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true, AllowAutoRedirect = true }) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };



public async Task<UserAccessToken> GetAuthenticationToken(string accessBrokerHost)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{accessBrokerHost}/Token")).ConfigureAwait(false); 


//accessBrokerHost is HTTP SPN created internally in a windows server


            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {                    
                throw new BrokerNotAvailableException();
            }
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserAccessToken>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }            
    }
```

> system.ComponentModel.win32Exception is throwing as GSSAPI operation failed with error - An invalid status code was supplied (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)

The above code is working fine in windows but not in Linux (I am using Linux Mint). As of my knowledge, it refers to a problem trying to use Kerberos but no Kerberos ticket is active to authenticate for Linux.

Comment: Thanks, @dustinos3 for the edit. I appreciate it.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29941 it seems like it's a bug from 1 year ago, what version are you using? maybe using the latest version would fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response israelss,  I am using netcoreapp2.2. I have seen so many things related to this issue including the link you suggested but I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: I may not be expert on c# but I'm kind of good at googling, lol, but also since the error mentions win32, which is not part of linux I guess it's not normal, it seems someone with the same issue fix it by stopping SocketsHttpHandler from overriding HttpHandler when you are  not in windows, this link explains it better.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266659/net-core-spnego-auth-with-httpclient

Comment: Thanks israelss, I have tried this already but didn't work. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to this question.

Solution 1:

Step 1. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52267046/11540588), you should add

```
 AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

Step 2. Since *UseDefaultCredentials = true* won't work here, you need to pass your Network credentials manually to HttpClient like below

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler{Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName" "Password", "Domain")}
```

Step 3. You should change your HttpRequestMessage version to

`HttpVersion.Version11`.

Solution 2: You can also fix this issue by converting your entire application into *NetcoreApp3.0*